# VsCode не видит импорты

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, импорт

[image: Скрин]

Vscode не видит импорт как это можно исправить? может есть какие то настройки или hotkey?

Comment: Что это за язык? Стоит поставить тег.

Comment: JavaScript, какой тег ?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас в VS code выставлен иной язык

Проверьте в панели снизу, JavaScript ли это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лично у меня все хорошо даже при том, что `B` не определен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да там JS проблема в том что редактор не видит большинство импортов но он все же видит и это раздражает часто ) думал может есть какой хоткей просто не смог найти в интернете

Comment: @Genesis, приложите пример инпутов